# What is the correct way to include a variable inside an Apache derby Export_Query

Tags: sql, derby

I am trying to export data from a derby table to a file. I'm having issues with the `WHERE` clause. What I have is this.

```
s.execute("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_EXPORT_QUERY('SELECT *FROM REPORT WHERE DATE = " + conversion.getDate() + " ' , 'C:\\Pos\\daily_report.csv' , ',' , null, null)");
```

This exception

> Java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "Sep" at
>   line 1, column 37.

was thrown while evaluating an expression.

Could someone direct me regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it.

> s.execute("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_EXPORT_QUERY('SELECT*FROM REPORT WHERE DATE = ' ' " + conversion.getDate() + " ' ' ' , 'C:\Pos\daily_report.csv' , ' , ' , null, null)");

Comment: You could also have used a `PreparedStatement` to avoid all that extra quoting. Regardless, glad you found a way that works for you.