# GemFireXD Export Query with date in the WHERE clause

Tags: oracle, gemfire

I am having problems with exporting output of a query to a .csv file in GemFireXD I have this command:

```
CALL SYSCS_UTIL.EXPORT_QUERY('select * from table where logtime >= '2017-02-26 00:00:00' and logtime <= '2016-02-27 00:00:00' order by logtime asc;', '/home/user/smsgateway-stats/smsgateway-stats-2017-02-26.csv', null, null, null);
```

GemFireXD seem to not like those single quotations around the date in the WHERE clause.

Note: logtime field is a TIMESTAMP data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape the single quotes surrounding the timestamps by using two of them to indicate that you mean a literal single quote:

```
CALL SYSCS_UTIL.EXPORT_QUERY('select * from table where logtime >=
    ''2017-02-26 00:00:00'' and logtime <= ''2016-02-27 00:00:00'' order by
    logtime asc;',
    '/home/user/smsgateway-stats/smsgateway-stats-2017-02-26.csv', null, null, null);
```

**Reference:** [What is the correct way to include a variable inside an Apache derby Export_Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39359923/what-is-the-correct-way-to-include-a-variable-inside-an-apache-derby-export-quer)